# How to test if a lock-free queue is correctly implemented?

Tags: c, multithreading, testing, data-structures, lock-free

I implemented a lock-free queue with the GCC `__sync_xxx_compare_and_swap` atomic builtin. Now I want to make sure that my code is correct. So I started multiple threads for enqueueing and dequeueing, and tried to:

- measure the number of enqueue and dequeue operations, and check if they match
- measure the number of times an individual element is enqueued and dequeued, and check if that number for each element is two (1 enqueueing and 1 dequeueing)

I found that the above two results are correct, but how can I verify that the enqueueing order is exactly the same as the dequeueing order? Or, is there any way to check the correctness of my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Helgrind: a thread error detector](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html). It's part of Valgrind. Be sure to read the manpage for extra goodies that can be enabled besides the default options.

As far as checking for re-ordering

1. generate only distinct items
2. log each action (en- & de-queue) for each thread in a per-thread log (a local variable in that thread, not a single global logfile!); this requires no synchronization
3. when each thread is about to end, save its log in a logfile.

When the program exits, you should then be able to match enqueues and dequeues in your logfile.

This is better than logging to a *single* logfile (protected by a mutex) *during* the test because it avoids a synchronization bottleneck (which would affect the thread dynamic and potentially make the test less relevant)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not so clear about the way for checking the ordering you just mentioned. First, what should each thread log to record the ordering? Second, I think there would be a race condition between the time of enqueueing and logging. Suppose we have two threads A and B, both performing `enqueue(); log();`. Then the result would be `enqueueA(); enqueueB(); logB(); logA();`, where thread B enqueues after A, but logs before A.

Comment: Maybe the key point here is that, the atomicity of "enqueue/dequeue" and "log something" is hard to guarantee.

Comment: What kind of errors are you hoping to catch? Obviously if you *enqueue from multiple threads with no synchronization*, you will **never be able to guarantee** a specific order in the queue, no matter how you implement the queue. Likewise if you *dequeue from multiple threads with no sync*, you will **never be able to know** what order the elements in the queue had.

Comment: I just want to make sure that my implementation is correct. You're right. I was thinking about to "record" the order of enqueue and dequeue in a specific run of the code. But that seems impossible. I cannot simply embed the code into the real project since that will be hard to debug if errors occur.

Comment: My comment above applies to *any* queue implementation, so that's not a reason against yours. But you need to think things through, read some failed code from other people, read some lock-free papers and thing again. And usually *forget the idea*. I too had a lock-free queue once that worked only on single-core ("uniprocessors"): http://fifoembed.sourceforge.net/